# Angular2 Quick Start - 'Cannot Get' Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I've been trying to do the quick start guide for Angular2. I did the example as instructed in the quick guide. However, when I ran it, it displayed the following message 'Cannot Get'. Does anyone know why this is happening?

**boot.js file**

```
// JavaScript source code
(function (app) {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

**The app.component.js file**

```
(function (app) {
    app.AppComponent = ng.core.Component({
        Selector: 'my-app',
        template: '<h1>My First Angular 2 App </h1>'
    })
    .class({
        constructor: function () { }
    });
})(window.app || window.app == {});
```

**The index file**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
    <script src='app/app.component.js'></script>
    <script src='app/boot.js'></script>

</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>

</html>
```

**Finally, the package.json file**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^1.3.1"
  }
}
```

I ran the line 'npm start' which opened the browser and displayed 'Cannot Get'

Comment: One gets Cannot GET when the server is unable to fetch the file (404). I got the same issue. Http Server looks for index.html at the directory from which it is triggered. Make sure you place the index.html at the folder root level from where you run the http server. Also, make sure app.component.js and boot.js are under app folder according to your html file. Hope it helps.

Comment: I had same issue while working with ng serve. But in my case it was some permission issues with folder inside which the angular application was kept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. I had an extra space in my html file which was causing the error. I removed the extra space, and it worked as expected.

Comment: Could you please provide more info about the "extra space" issue?

Comment: Was having same issue. the extra space was at the end of index.html file.

Comment: Something during ng serve is sticking in the extra space. is there any permanent solution?

Comment: It was a typo on my part and had nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score 55):

I got this error when index.html was not in the correct folder.

If that is the case, putting it in the main angular project's root folder should resolve the error.

Comment: That means inside angular2-quickstart. You may have it in the folder app.

Comment: You cannot add a tutorial and get people P'ed off and confused on the word GO, - Thanks very much for your help. As an extra tip if you are following the tutorial here 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html
then moving ONLY the 'index' and the 'Styles.CSS' page should sort this out.

Comment: Is there a way to override that behaviour? Lets say /src/app   and /src/index.html  instead of /app and /index.html ?

Answer (score 16):

### Background

I have had the same problem: `Cannot GET / pagename` on every page. I searched the internet but did not found a solution like this one.

My project resided inside a folder with ASCII spaces since the repository name also contained spaces.

## Answer

The folder in which your project resides, should not contain any space or ASCII Character "%20".

[image]

After this change my project did not give the `Cannot GET / pagename` error.

Comment: This answer should get more votes, I've literally wasted more than 10hours on this issue.

Comment: @Luther yes took me also way to long, I did not saw this solution anywhere on the internet.

Comment: @Brampage Thanks for this answer..Took me several hours debugging my code before finding your answer..

Answer (score 3):

Cannot GET / error comes when your angular project fails to compile. So, first ensure you are not having any error in your angular code and it compiles fine. Just use this command:

```
ng serve
```

and it should list all issues your angular code has.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue because I forgot to add the `bs-config.json` file that we can see in the "Final structure" part of the tutorial. 
It should contain :

```
{
  "server": {
    "baseDir": "src",
    "routes": {
      "/node_modules": "node_modules"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using routes, make sure you have a correctly imported component pointing to the "" (/ route).

example: 
`{ path: "", component: MyHomeComponent }`

Full example of `app.module.ts` in an Angular 5 installation (same same from Angular +2...)

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { CinemaService } from "./services/cinema.service";
import { MyHomeComponent } from "./components/my-home/my-home.component";
import { MyMovieComponent } from "./components/my-movie/my-movie.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", component: MyHomeComponent },
  { path: "movie/:id", component: MyMovieComponent },

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyHomeComponent,
    MyMovieComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [CinemaService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Angular.io example "minimal NgModule"
They gave us the files with extra "0" in the file names.
I solved the issue by converting only file name "index.0.html" to "index.html"
It finally worked :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run 'ng serve' command where your 'src' folder lies.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error just because I made some changes in `angular-cli.json` file then I ran my app and got error as

```
 " Cannot GET / ".
```

Then I removed the changes made in `angular-cli.json` file and ran the app. It was working fine.

Comment: What were the "some changes"?

Answer (score -1):

in addition to what Melaz said, I had the same problem with just an HTML file (no react, angular) and I solved the problem just by changing the file's name to index.html