# Unclear error + text dynamic text not working

Tags: angular, npm, atom-editor

ENV

```
@angular/cli: 1.2.4
node: 6.11.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.3.1
@angular/common: 4.3.1
@angular/compiler: 4.3.1
@angular/core: 4.3.1
@angular/forms: 4.3.1
@angular/http: 4.3.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.3.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.1
@angular/router: 4.3.1
@angular/cli: 1.2.4
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.3.1
@angular/language-service: 4.3.1
```

I am new to Angular 4(but not previous experience either with any Angular, only some JS), so I started a basic [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htPYk6QxacQ&t=1353s), unfortunately I am already got some different behavior as it should be, even I am really simply following the tutorial, so I would like to understand from the beginning and not leaving something behind as it is the beginning.

That is my version:

Unfortunately I am not able to have list packages installed but Atom is up-to-date and I do have already installed the [atom-typescript](https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript)[image]

That is the only 2 file I did have changed in this way as from tutorial

I am not getting the dynamic Text as here:

[image: text not rendered dynamically as should be]

Even though my files are:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
name ='';
}
```

and app.component.html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" [( ngModel )]="name">
<p>{{ name }}</p>
```

What should be changed from the tutorial, I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I did not change anything and instead now I got the :

Cannot GET /

error, but I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800254/angular2-quick-start-cannot-get-message), my index file is in the right place and I don't have any extra space, ideed:

[image]

Comment: I think you are loading the wrong angular version (1.2.4) and you are using the wrong tutorial. Just get your hands dirty with npm and use the angular cli to get started: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart.

Comment: Sorry but related to what I am loading the wrong Angular version?The tutorial is called Angular 4 but is intended for Angular 2, is just a name the author gave, not sure which exactly version though for such basic statment I hope should not change from version to version. Also as you can see I already installed angular CLI.