# Error: Cannot GET / - Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have a little problem with my Angular2 app. After configuring the app-routing.module (root module routing), I've got a problem with the server. Every HTTP request to the server has the same error.

```
Cannot GET /
```

This is my app-routing.module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/index', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

How you can see, the root route redirect to a route configured in another module. The module it's called landing & this is the landing.module:

import { LandingRoutingModule } from './landing-routing.module';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './components/landing-page/landing-page.component';

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    LandingRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [LandingPageComponent]
})
export class LandingModule { }
```

& of course, the landing-routing.module:

import { LandingPageComponent } from './components/landing-page/landing-page.component';

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/index', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'index', component: LandingPageComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LandingRoutingModule { }
```

The root route for this module just redirects to the index route using the LandingPageComponent. The component only has modifications in the HTML & CSS file.

And my app.module (root) look like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

/*
  Modulos Personalizados
*/
import { LandingModule } from './modules/landing/landing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LandingModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: where is the error trace ? can you share it?

Comment: Also i'm not sure this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800254/angular2-quick-start-cannot-get-message

Comment: can you show error log

Comment: Hello and Thank´s for take your time and comment this questions. From nothing, the App comes back to life, solving the problem by his own.

Comment: @CarlosFuentes possibly because of the folder name in which your project resides? (I have added an [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46299865/1265945))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Quick Start - 'Cannot Get' Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800254/angular2-quick-start-cannot-get-message)

Comment: @CarlosFuentes I have added an answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46299803/1265945