# Angular: Cannot Get /

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to open, build and run someone else's Angular 4 project but I am not able to view the project when I run it my way. I don't see what is going wrong or what I should do now. I already had everything in place to use NPM and NodeJS

The steps I took were:

- Open up the project
- npm install
- ng serve

The project compiles the right way. (I have an own Angular app and I know how this looks like) The console is showing:

> '** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200 **'.

Then, when I opened up a web browser, I navigated to localhost:4200 and a web page with the following text were shown:

> 'Cannot GET /'

And on the console was the following text:

> 'GET http://localhost:4200/ 404 (Not Found)'

The project should work fine but I am not able to navigate to a working URL on the web page. Routing is set-up another way as I am used to doing this. In app.module.ts the following is implemented:

app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: '',   redirectTo: 'tree', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ path: 'admin', component: AdminPanelComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
children: [{path:'', component: PanelComponent},{path: 'add', component: 
AddTreeComponent}, {path:'manage-trees', component:ManageTreesComponent}, 
{path:'manage-users', component: ManageUsersComponent}, {path:'view-trees', 
component: ViewTreeComponent}]},
{path:'tree', component: TreeComponent},
{path:'error', component: ErrorComponent},
{path:'unauthorized', component: UnauthorizedComponent},
{path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
{path:'entire-tree', component: EntireTreeComponent},
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

Also opening up a web page like; localhost:4200/tree does not work. When I let angular stop serving the web page, the web page displays: "this site can't be reached'. So I think there is running something at localhost:4200... Also, another project of this person behaves the same way.

[image]

Does anybody know what is going on?

**EDIT**

app.module.ts

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { useHash: true })
```

Package.json

```
{
"name": "xxx",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"angular-oauth2-oidc": "^1.0.20",
"angular-polyfills": "^1.0.1",
"angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
"angular2-spinner": "^1.0.10",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^1.8.0",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.2.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
"karma": "~1.7.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
"protractor": "~5.1.2",
"ts-node": "~3.0.4",
"tslint": "~5.3.2",
"typescript": "~2.3.3"
 }
}
```

I also see an icon next to the tab name with the label: "Error".

**OBSERVATION:**

New observation:

After I ran `npm install -g angular-cli` I wasn't able to run `ng serve`. (You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the build command after reinstall of angular-cli)

Then I ran `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest` and I was able to use `ng serve` again.

**OBSERVATION 2:**

After building the app with: 'ng build ...' there is no index.html in the 'dist' folder... When I set the website online, there is just a folder structure instead of a nice website. I think that's because there is no index.html.

Comment: hey, could you show package.json file?

Comment: Tried to navigate `http://localhost:4200/#` ?

Comment: Good question AnteJablanAdamović. Unfortunately this gives the same result. Same as with: http://localhost:4200/#/tree

Comment: Without the complete code it's hard to say, but it should work.

Comment: Does it behave any differently if you take off the `, { useHash: true }`

Comment: @DeborahK This gives the same result

Comment: I usually use base path as children nested under a general `''` path :     
`{ path: '', component: RootComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
     { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}, /* your other routes... */] },`

Comment: What does your server(terminal) output when you run `ng-serve` and open up the webpage?

Comment: The terminal just outputs a hash and its js file, plus the status message: "Compiled successfully". Going to the website does not create any other output than mentioned above.

Comment: One of the top reasons for this error is because if some errors in your actual code. Check your console, probably angular would log some errors.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was that I ran the commands within the folder `/project/src/app`. Navigating back to the project folder so to `/project` and running `ng serve` from there solved my problem.

Answer (score 124):

The way I resolved this error was by finding and fixing the error that the **console** reported.

Run `ng build` in your command line/terminal, and it should display a useful error, such as the example in red here: *Property 'name' does not exist on type 'object'*.

[image: Console example]

Comment: The `ng serve` also may run building/compilation. Same message appeared for both commands.

Answer (score 49):

For me it also was problem with path, but I had percentage sign in the root folder.

After I **replaced %20 with space**, it started to work :)

Comment: Ugh, this was also the fix for me - for reference I'm on a mac & it worked fine in a windows box

Comment: This is perfect, saved my day. Basically I cloned repository from azure devops which has space in the repository name. Thanks alot.

Comment: which file are you talking about?

Comment: I was writing about name of main folder with code e.g. I cloned project "My Project"  from Azure Devops and it created folder "My%20Project" on my disk

Comment: Wow thanks for this, I spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to debug this. The fix is as you say, remove the special chars from the parent directory name.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error caused by build errors. I ran ng build in the directory of my application which helped me correct my errors

Comment: Being able to diagnose the error is very helpful. thanks

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with an Angular 9.

In my case, I changed the angular.json file from

```
"aot": true
```

To

```
"aot": false
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Check if in `index.html` base is set

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```

Comment: can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800254/angular2-quick-start-cannot-get-message/46299803#46299803

Comment: Thanks, but my project folder does not contain any space.

Comment: how about other routes ? are they working as expected ?

Comment: No, none of them.

Comment: I have this included, but still get the error

Answer (score 4):

I was using `export class TestCalendar implements OnInit{}` but i did not write the function

```
 ngOnInit() {
    /* Display initial */
  }
```

. After running the command `ng serve` , i found out that i was not using `ngOnInit(){}` . Once i implemented, it started working fine. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

Just figured out the reason when we type "ng serve" INSIDE OUR PROJECT..
for example `C:\Users\EdgeTech1\Desktop\CSharp\WebAPI\MyProject>ng serve`

could not resolve module `C:\Users\EdgeTech1\Desktop\C`
results: `failed compiled`

root cause:
My folder name was `C# Project..`

Note: I tried to remove the `#` in my Project Name, I rename `C# Project` to `CSharp` instead and I tried to open `cmd` prompt again, typed the same thing..

for example:

```
C:\Users\EdgeTech1\Desktop\CSharp\WebAPI\MyProject>ng serve
```

and my project compiled successfully.. so as much as possible avoid ASCII characters in naming projects files.

Comment: This is what solved the problem in my case. Project had a space ascii %20 between two words and that's what was triggering CSP error. Quite interesting. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This is what my issue was as well -- had C# instead of CSharp in the file path. Unreal that it gave some random error about CSS / bootstrap webpack for me. So, so, SO stupid.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with an Angular 6+ app and ASP.NET Core 2.0

I had just previously tried to change the Angular app from CSS to SCSS.

My solution was to go to the `src/angularApp` folder and running `ng serve`. This helped me realize that I had missed changing the `src/styles.css` file to `src/styles.scss`

Comment: I am hitting the same situation, but I have changed the file name and this is still hosing, me. I can also build the package successfully in the context of the angular app. Is there anything that dotnet cannot deal with unexpected file renames or something?

Answer (score 2):

I was referring to one of my provider with two different casing. One of them was wrong but only the webpack compiler was complaining. I had to step into the ClientApp folder and use ng build or ng serve to see the errors. (ASP.NET Core SPA with Angular 5)

Answer (score 2):

Check baseHref is set to "/" ( angular.cli )

```
    "architect": {
        "build": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
            "options": {
                "baseHref": "/"
```

if it didn't work, check if your base href in your index.html is set to "/"

Comment: I had it set to "./" to make it actually work when built. But apparently, Angular doesn't know how to deal with it... So, I will have to use the build parameter --base-href "./"  to get it set properly during build time.

Answer (score 2):

Many answers dont really make sense but still have upvotes, makes me currious why that would still work in some cases.

In `angular.json`

```
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
  "options": {
    "deployUrl": "/",
    "baseHref": "/",
```

worked for me.

Comment: deployUrl is deprecated, but in my case setting 'baseHref' to "./" caused the error. So, I now set the baseHref only as a parameter to the build command.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was with @Component Selector path was pointing to wrong path. After changing it solved the issue.

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-fetch-data',
templateUrl: './fetch-data.component.html',
providers: [ToolbarService, GroupService, FilterService, PageService, ExcelExportService, PdfExportService]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can apparently happen for a number of reasons. Here is my experience for those who land here after searching for "Cannot GET /"

I experienced this error when I installed ng-bootstrap v6 into an Angular 8 project. I downgraded ng-bootstrap to v5 and it seems to be okay now, since ng-bootstrap v6 is only compatible with Angular 9.

This happened while working in Visual Studio 2019 with the Angular .NET Core template. At the same time, the output panel of Visual Studio displayed this esoteric sounding error: "TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in ambient context," which led me here, which, after a little reading, made me think it was a versioning issue. It appears that it was.

I fixed it by changing "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.0"," to "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.0.0" in the package.json file and rebuilding.

Answer (score 1):

if you changed any name or file component , check if it is the right name

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NewNameComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  exports:[
    NewNameComponent
     ]
})
export class YourModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is a versioning issue. Node.js v8 cannot compile with angular-cli 6.0 or later. angularcli v6 and above will work for lastest node versions. Please make sure if your node version is v8, then you need to install angular-cli upto 1.7.4.
enter ng -v command in cmd and check the cli and node versions.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer [here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/1280#issuecomment-196731964). You need to redirect all routes that Node is not using to Angular:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./server/views/index.html')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the errors after stopping debbuging by choosing the option to display ASP.NET Core Web Server output in the output window.
In my case I was pointing to a different templateUrl.

Comment: Your answer is not clear enough.
Please elaborate to make it more useful to the community.

Answer (score 0):

First, delete existing files **package.lock.json** and **node_modules** from your project.
Then, the first step is to write **npm cache clean --force**. Second, also write this command **npm i** on the terminal. This process resolve my error. **:D**

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that I had saved my project folder under C:\Users\... which indeed is a problem. After I saved it under C:\ then `npm install` and `ng serve --open` it worked just fine!

Comment: I have my code under C:\Users\... and it works just fine. I got this error when I forgot to do npm install after a colleague had updated our packages.

Answer (score 0):

In my angular.json file the `deployUrl` was set to `static/ang`.

```
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "deployUrl": "/static/ang/",
             ....
```

This was causing my application to get served from `localhost:4200/static/ang`

Removing `deployUrl` fixed it for me.

EDIT:
I shifted deployUrl to under `configurations` since it was important when building for production. (Since my lazy loaded chunks were not getting served on the static url).

```
"architect": {
            "build": {
              "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
              "options": {
                 ....
                 ....
               },
               "configurations": {
                  "deployUrl": "/static/ang/",
```

Answer (score 0):

Bumped into same issue, I tried this:
-ng build

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Another problem may be that you're importing the component instead of it's module.

```js
imports: [
  YourComponent, // <-- Should be YourComponentModule
]
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the Angular project was not getting compiled when executing because of some undelared variable in the ts file which was binded to an html tag.
You can use `ng serve --verbose true` to display the build log in terminal to check where the application is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

A cause of the problem could be that one of your input properties (variable after the @Input() decorator) being sent to a component is not being read properly, e.g. an array is being read as a string.  It could be that a variable was accessed by a component properly, e.g.

```
<app-component variable={{variable}}></app-component>
```

instead of

```
<app-component [variable]="variable"></app-component>
```

The later being the correct way.

Answer (score -1):

The weird thing that I was experiencing was that I could make changes to the components in Visual Studio 2019 while the app was running and see my changes but, when I restarted the app, I got the Cannot Get / error. Instead of running IIS Express, I chose to run the app using Angular JS and the build window showed me that there was an error in app.component.ts. It turned out to be an extra } at the end of the file. Not sure how it got there but, when I removed it, the app works fine.

Comment: How is this an answer to the original question?

Comment: As a newbie to Angular, I too was getting the "Cannot Get /" error. It could be as simple as a syntax error. I was able to discover where the bug was by running the code with Angular JS instead of IIS Express in Visual Studio. The command window told me exactly which file was causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks, that could indeed be helpful for someone.

Answer (score -2):

For me the issue was that my local CLI was not the same version as my global CLI - updating it by running the following command solved the problem:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score -2):

Deleting node modules folder worked for me.

- Delete the node modules folder
- Run `npm install`.
- Re-run the application and it should work.