# Cannot GET / error

Tags: node.js, angular, visual-studio, single-page-application

looked for couple of hours, on how to solve that, but no luck.

I am using VS 2017 preview edition, and trying to open ASP.NET core 2.0 web application, that uses Angular template

when i open the site (f5 or ctrl-f5), the web-browser getting opened with the message

> Cannot GET /

[image]

I don't know what causing that and how to fix that, tried to clean/rebuild/restart VS/change project port number/restart the computer, what else can I do to solve that?

Comment: i found out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34800254/angular2-quick-start-cannot-get-message) that `Cannot Get / ` actually point to an error in app.. (weird) i spent couple of hours looking for all different solution.
What i did is from the Client app folder i run the command `ng serve` and it pointed me to the error.. (i forgot to introduced some variable (i run the app from VS, so it does the ng serve automatically, and said nothing about that error)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what error you have in the client application, the server might not start at all. Local errors like undeclared locals are seldom a problem.

Usually, the web server does not start when a dependency of the module marked as `bootstrap` is missing, like, for example `entryComponents'.

Another thing that can cause the boostrap to fail, is a missing file: in this case you should have a look at `templateUrl` and `styleUrls`.

Manually compiling via `ng build` (or better `ng build --prod`) will point you to the offending code.